# HTML5 geolocation app for Android using phonegap eclipse

Tags: android, html, google-maps, geolocation, cordova

I am having trouble to get this HTML5 geolocation app for Android running. The app works fine in Firefox browser from my desktop, but once I compile it using Eclipse - PhoneGap, the geolocation button does not perform the command document.write, I have tried with alert(), as well as console.log(), but there is no positive result.

The code is below, can you please point to me if I am missing setting up any of the phone sensors for geolocation?

```
Below is the code:

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title> Geolocation Test </title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>  // Begginning  of Google Maps script

window.google = window.google || {};
google.maps = google.maps || {};
(function() {

  function getScript(src) {
    document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"' +
                   ' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');
  }

  var modules = google.maps.modules = {};
  google.maps.__gjsload__ = function(name, text) {
    modules[name] = text;
  };

  google.maps.Load = function(apiLoad) {
    delete google.maps.Load;
    apiLoad([0.009999999776482582,[[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"m@219000000"],[["http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=131\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://khm1.googleapis.com/kh?v=131\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,1,"131"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,"imgtp=png32\u0026",null,"h@219000000"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=t@131,r@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=t@131,r@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"t@131,r@219000000"],null,null,[["http://cbk0.googleapis.com/cbk?","http://cbk1.googleapis.com/cbk?"]],[["http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=77\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://khm1.googleapis.com/kh?v=77\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"77"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026"]]],["en-US","US",null,0,null,null,"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/","http://csi.gstatic.com","https://maps.googleapis.com","http://maps.googleapis.com"],["http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/5","3.13.5"],[2518365001],1.0,null,null,null,null,1,"",["places"],null,0,"http://khm.googleapis.com/mz?v=131\u0026",null,"https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com","https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com",null,"http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon"], loadScriptTime);
  };
  var loadScriptTime = (new Date).getTime();
  getScript("http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/5/%7Bmain,places%7D.js");
})();

</script> / End of Google Maps script

<script> // Script that runs the app    

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#startGeo').click(checkLocation);

    function checkLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, locationFail);


        }
        else {
        document.write('You dont have geolocation');
        }
    } // ends checkLocation()

    function getLocation(position) {

        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        var timestamp = position.timestamp;

        document.write(' latitude: ' + latitude + ' longitude: ' + longitude + ' accuracy: ' + accuracy + ' timestamp: ' + timestamp);



    }
    function locationFail()  {
    document.write('We did not get your location. You are safe from big broda');
    }    

});


</script>

</headd>

<body>
<button id="startGeo"> Click here for geolocation  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.write seems to be the cause of your problem, rather than a failure in geolocation, assuming of course you have adequate permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title> Geolocation Test </title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>  // Begginning  of Google Maps script

window.google = window.google || {};
google.maps = google.maps || {};
(function() {

  function getScript(src) {
    document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"' +
                   ' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');
  }

  var modules = google.maps.modules = {};
  google.maps.__gjsload__ = function(name, text) {
    modules[name] = text;
  };

  google.maps.Load = function(apiLoad) {
    delete google.maps.Load;
    apiLoad([0.009999999776482582,[[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"m@219000000"],[["http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=131\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://khm1.googleapis.com/kh?v=131\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,1,"131"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,"imgtp=png32\u0026",null,"h@219000000"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=t@131,r@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=t@131,r@219000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"t@131,r@219000000"],null,null,[["http://cbk0.googleapis.com/cbk?","http://cbk1.googleapis.com/cbk?"]],[["http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=77\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","http://khm1.googleapis.com/kh?v=77\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"77"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=en-US\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026"]]],["en-US","US",null,0,null,null,"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/","http://csi.gstatic.com","https://maps.googleapis.com","http://maps.googleapis.com"],["http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/5","3.13.5"],[2518365001],1.0,null,null,null,null,1,"",["places"],null,0,"http://khm.googleapis.com/mz?v=131\u0026",null,"https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com","https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com",null,"http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon"], loadScriptTime);
  };
  var loadScriptTime = (new Date).getTime();
  getScript("http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/5/%7Bmain,places%7D.js");
})();

</script> / End of Google Maps script

<script> // Script that runs the app    

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#startGeo').click(checkLocation);

    function checkLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, locationFail);
        }
        else {
        $('#result').append('You dont have geolocation');
        }
    } // ends checkLocation()

    function getLocation(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        var timestamp = position.timestamp;

        $('#result').append("location: "+' latitude: ' + latitude + ' longitude: ' + longitude + ' accuracy: ' + accuracy + ' timestamp: ' + timestamp);


    }
    function locationFail()  {
    $('#result').append('We did not get your location. You are safe from big broda');
    }    

});


</script>

</head>

<body>
<button id="startGeo"> Click here for geolocation  </button>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

BTW, there's a typo in your source code `</headd>` should be `</head>`.

You should also really use `$(document).on("deviceready")` instead of `$(document).ready()` with Phonegap as 'ready' event only indicates DOM is ready whereas 'deviceready' indicates Phonegap has fully loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now!.                                            As for your suggestion about using  $(document).on("deviceready") instead of $(document).ready(), should the first line of the call be like this? When I change it to $(document).on("deviceready", function () the button no longer works...

Comment: Glad that I could help :-) Please accept my answer so other people know it has been answered. For the deviceready event, your syntax looks correct so I'm not sure why that's not working - maybe try using bind: `$(document).bind("deviceready",function(){...});` The Phonegap documentation for the deviceready event is [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) if it helps...